Problems with the click event in a TableLayout and view pager in android studio
i was working on an app where i was trying to build tab layout and insert fragments in that but in starting it was blinking and after that it was neither being clicked or being Scrolled

Problems with the click event in a TableLayout. 
 


package com.example.myapplication7;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TableLayout;

import androidx.activity.EdgeToEdge;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.core.graphics.Insets;
import androidx.core.view.ViewCompat;
import androidx.core.view.WindowInsetsCompat;
import androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager;

import com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
TabLayout tb;
ViewPager pager;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        EdgeToEdge.enable(this);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ViewCompat.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener(findViewById(R.id.main), (v, insets) -> {
            Insets systemBars = insets.getInsets(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.systemBars());
            v.setPadding(systemBars.left, systemBars.top, systemBars.right, systemBars.bottom);
            tb= findViewById(R.id.tablayout);

            tb.addTab(tb.newTab().setText("Chats"));
            tb.addTab(tb.newTab().setText("Status"));

            pager = findViewById(R.id.viewPager);

            pager.requestTransparentRegion(pager);
            fadapter ad = new fadapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

            pager.setAdapter(ad);
            tb.setupWithViewPager(pager);
            return insets;
        });
    }
}

i am looking for a direct answer which will help me to sort out this problem

yes a very simple way to solve it out is please insert your code

` tb= findViewById(R.id.tablayout);
    tb.addTab(tb.newTab().setText("Chats"));
    tb.addTab(tb.newTab().setText("Status"));

    pager = findViewById(R.id.viewPager);

    pager.requestTransparentRegion(pager);
    fadapter ad = new fadapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

    pager.setAdapter(ad);
    tb.setupWithViewPager(pager); <code>`

this code from outside your setOnApplyWindowsListener(){}
like this

package com.example.myapplication7;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TableLayout;

import androidx.activity.EdgeToEdge;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.core.graphics.Insets;
import androidx.core.view.ViewCompat;
import androidx.core.view.WindowInsetsCompat;

import androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager;
import com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout;
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
TabLayout tb;
ViewPager pager;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    EdgeToEdge.enable(this);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    tb= findViewById(R.id.tablayout);

    tb.addTab(tb.newTab().setText("Chats"));
    tb.addTab(tb.newTab().setText("Status"));

    pager = findViewById(R.id.viewPager);

    pager.requestTransparentRegion(pager);
    fadapter ad = new fadapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

    pager.setAdapter(ad);
    tb.setupWithViewPager(pager);
    ViewCompat.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener(findViewById(R.id.main), (v, 
insets) -> {
        Insets systemBars = 
insets.getInsets(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.systemBars());
        v.setPadding(systemBars.left, systemBars.top, systemBars.right, 
systemBars.bottom);

        return insets;
    });
}

}
